# Send ajax array to asp page?

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

Im trying to send some checkbox values as an array and then insert it to my database, but I can't get the array values into variables in my asp page?
I want to get the array values into variables kalnr0=arrayvalue0, kalnr1=arrayvalue1 etc…

I have this now: And it shows the alert(texten) that say its an array.

Im sending the form with ajax  method="GET"
and the form field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="kalendrar_id[]" value="<%=rs("kalendrar_id")%>">
```

and on my receiving asp page I have this:

```
Dim kalendrar_id
kalendrar_id=request.querystring("kalendrar_id[]")
kalitem = Split(kalendrar_id, ",")
japp=array(kalitem)

If IsArray(japp) then 
For i = 0 To UBound(kalitem)
On Error resume next
Response.Write kalnr(i)=i   
Next
texten= " is an array"
Else
texten= " not an array"
End If
```

So how do I get the array values into the below variables?

```
kalnr0=Cstr(kalitem(0))
kalnr1=Cstr(kalitem(1))
kalnr2=Cstr(kalitem(2))
kalnr3=Cstr(kalitem(3))
kalnr4=Cstr(kalitem(4))
```

I really need some help with this, thanks :-)

If I set kalendrar_id="1,2,3,4,5" then it works, so kalendrar_id=request.querystring("kalendrar_id[]") is not getting any value, or its the wrong value!?

And if I post the form the normal way, not with ajax then it works, so somehow the query string request.querystring("kalendrar_id[]") is wrong, could it be something with encoding?

SOLVED. I had to remove [ ] from the form field, not sure what else, have tried so many things ;-)

Comment: You don't need `array()`; `Split` already produces an array. Also, I can't quite tell what you're having trouble with: are you not getting the values from the form, or is it the array-to-numbered-variable conversion that's tripping you up? (Note that the "solution" to the latter problem is "don't do that".)

Comment: Martha, hi. I can't get the array values into my variables. I don´t know what Im doing wrong? I know that the texten="is an array" is showed in my ajax callback, but I can't know for sure if the array really has any or the right value!
I simply needs to get the array values into my database, and I can't just set kalitem(0) as a value thats inserted to my db!? So I thought that I must first get the array values into variables, or should I do it?

Comment: I don't understand why you think you can't use `kalitem(i)` directly. As far as figuring out what your form is returning, that's what `Response.Write Request.Querystring("kalendrar_id[]")` is for.

Answer (score 0):

First off, if your question is how to put something like the following into a loop...

```
var1 = var(1)
var2 = var(2)
...
var5 = var(5)
```

... the answer is **don't do that**. :) (*"Doctor, it hurts when I press here." "So don't press there."*)

Second, you don't need to use both `Split()` and `Array()`. `Split()` already produces an array, so the second function isn't doing anything useful.

Third, I'm not sure why you're using square brackets in the field names. If you think they'll somehow magically make your form return an array, well, they won't. All they'll do is make some servers eat your form results. (Not all servers, which is why square brackets are allowed in form field names, but they're still not a good idea, especially with `method="get"`.)

To debug an issue like yours, the first thing to try is to look at what the form is returning. With `method="get"`, you could just look at the querystring in the address bar, but it's better to explicitly see what the *server* thinks it's getting:

```
Response.Write "fieldname=" & Request.Querystring("fieldname") & "<br>"
```

If that doesn't get you what you expect, then you need to make sure the form field is actually named what you think it is. If yes, the next step is to double-check that the form is getting filled out - i.e. is the reason it's not returning a value the fact that there's no value to return?